# how to parse the key value dictionary data

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value, jsondecoder

I have json as below.

```
{
  "CHF": 1.0064,
  "KZT": 0.0027,
  "ZAR": 0.0676,
  "INR": 0.0136,
  "CNY": 0.1456,
  "UZS": 0.0001,
  "AUD": 0.7062,
  "KRW": 0.0009
}
```

This is nothing but list of currency & their rates.

I am confused how to parse this data.

Usually I was creating Model to parse the json data as below for User data (& not for above case).

```
struct UserData : Decodable {
    var firstName : String?
    var lastName : String?
}
```

& while parsing I have as below.

```
let globalErrObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: data!)
```

However as this is key value data, I am confused how Model & parsing would be.

Comment: Is this the whole JSON? to parse this you need to use a Dictionary, `[String: Decimal]`

Comment: How does `"CHF": 1.0064` relate to `firstName, lastName`?

Comment: This JSON will be parsed to a Dictionary of String keys and Double values. If you want something like array of objects from this dictionary where object is as struct which contains currencyName and value as properties, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @AshleyMills : Updated question... I show that as sample for parsing user data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to decode the JSON as `[String:Double]` and map it to an array of a custom struct

```
struct Rate {
    let name : String
    let value : Double
}


let rates = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Double].self, from: data!).map(Rate.init)
```